# change a subset of elements' values in theano matrix

Tags: python, theano

I want to create a **mask** matrix dynamically, for example, in `numpy`

```
mask = numpy.zeros((5,5))
row = numpy.arange(5)
col = [0, 2, 3, 0, 1]
mask[row, col] += 1   # that is setting some values to `1`
```

Here is what I tried in `theano`,

```
mask = tensor.zeros((5,5))
row = tensor.ivector('row')
col = tensor.ivector('col')
mask = tensor.set_subtensor(mask[row, col], 1)
```

the above `theano` code failed with error message: `not supported`.
Any other ways?

Comment: Works for me on `0.6.0` (did `import theano.tensor as tensor` and copied and pasted your code). When exactly do you get the error message?

Comment: Usually `set_subtensor` is actually used as an update. Maybe you are getting the error at the construction of a function? In that case, could you post the exact code, including imports, that leads to this, and the exact error message?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me on `0.6.0`. I used your code and created a function from it to check the output. Try copying and pasting this:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor

mask = tensor.zeros((5,5))
row = tensor.ivector('row')
col = tensor.ivector('col')
mask = tensor.set_subtensor(mask[row, col], 1)

f = theano.function([row, col], mask)

print f(np.array([0, 1, 2]).astype(np.int32), np.array([1, 2, 3]).astype(np.int32))
```

This yields

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```